# Customizing GtkStack transitions with CSS

Tags: c, css, widget, gtk3

The `GtkStack` class provides the method : `gtk_stack_set_transition_type` to enable transitions between pages.

But only the follwing transition types are available :

```
typedef enum {
  GTK_STACK_TRANSITION_TYPE_NONE,
  GTK_STACK_TRANSITION_TYPE_CROSSFADE,
  GTK_STACK_TRANSITION_TYPE_SLIDE_RIGHT,
  GTK_STACK_TRANSITION_TYPE_SLIDE_LEFT,
  GTK_STACK_TRANSITION_TYPE_SLIDE_UP,
  GTK_STACK_TRANSITION_TYPE_SLIDE_DOWN,
  GTK_STACK_TRANSITION_TYPE_SLIDE_LEFT_RIGHT,
  GTK_STACK_TRANSITION_TYPE_SLIDE_UP_DOWN
} GtkStackTransitionType;
```

Is there a way to define a custom transition using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, there currently isn't a way to specify a transition in CSS for GTK widgets, and for `GtkStack` in particular.